# Алгоритм Форда-Беллмана работает некорректно на некоторых тестах. Не могу понять в чём ошибка

Tags: c++, графы

уже очень долго сижу и не могу понять, где ошибка в моей реализации алгоритма Беллмана-Форда.

Задан ориентированный граф, в нём не может быть петель и кратных рёбер. Необходимо найти длину кратчайшего пути от заданной вершины first до заданной вершины last. Вершины имеют только положительные номера, не превышающие 3*10^5, количество рёбер не более 10^5. Длина ребра не более 10^9 и не менее -10^9.

Входные данные: на первой строке поочерёдно идут количество вершин, количество рёбер, вершина first и вершина last. Далее идут m строк, содержащих информацию о рёбрах - первая, вторая вершина и цена ребра.

Пример ввода:

```
5 6 1 5
1 2 2
1 3 0
3 2 -1
2 4 1
3 4 4
4 5 5
```

На выход идёт только длина кратчайшего пути.

Мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#define inf 9223372036854775807


struct Edge
{
    int start, fin, len;//начальная вершина, конечная вершина и цена ребра соответственно
};


int main()
{
    int n, m;
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    //считываем кол-во вершин n, рёбер m, начальную вершину first и конечную last
    fin >> n;
    fin >> m;
    fin >> first;
    fin >> last;


    //создаём вектор кратчайших путей из вершины first в остальные
    vector<long long int> d(n, inf);
    d[first - 1] = 0;


    //вектор смежных вершин
    vector<Edge> edges(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        fin >> edges[i].start >> edges[i].fin >> edges[i].len;
    }
    
    fin.close();

    //Беллман-Форд
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if ((d[edges[j].start - 1] + edges[j].len) < d[edges[j].fin - 1])
            {
                d[edges[j].fin - 1] = d[edges[j].start - 1] + edges[j].len;
            }
        }
    }
    //проверка на отрицательные циклы
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if ((d[edges[j].start - 1] + edges[j].len) < d[edges[j].fin - 1])
        {
            cout << "Negative cycle";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << d[last - 1];
}
```

Мой код проходит большинство тестов в тестирующей системе. Однако на одном из них выдаёт ошибку WA (wrong answer). В чём ошибка не понимаю.

Comment: Забыл добавить. По условию между вершинами first и last обязательно есть путь.

Comment: Нашёл ошибку в создании вектора кратчайших путей. (d[0] = 0; должно быть d[first - 1] = 0;) Однако на некоторых тестах всё равно есть ошибка.

Comment: `Длина ребра не более 10^9 и не менее -10^9`  в int не влезет. тут порядка 10^14 сумма может быть

Comment: Суммы длин хранятся в векторе "d", а он long long int

Comment: а inf чему равно?

Comment: ой, извиняюсь, забыл скопировать из оригинального кода. inf равен верхней границе long long int

Comment: никогда так не делайте. как минимум на 2 делите. иначе вы можете получить что-то в стиле inf + 1 = -inf < inf - путь из ниоткуда

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но в данном случае ошибка вряд-ли связана с этим.

Comment: Всё-таки вы оказались правы. Ошибка была не только в этом, но и указанная вами тоже повлияла на некорректную работу кода. Спасибо.